# The fact that the type of function determined in runtime is defined as advantage?

Tags: c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

I read that one advantage of using by "inheritance" for generic-code is "the fact that the type of the object determined in runtime", because that allows more flexibility.

I don't understand this point. How it's really allows more flexibility?

---

If for example I get object from type that derived `Base` , so that:

```
class Base{  
public:   
virtual void method() const { /* ... */ }
};

class D1 : public Base{  
public:   
 void method() const override { /* ... */ }
};

class D2 : public Base{  
public:   
 void method() const override { /* ... */ }
};
```

And I send to function `f` (for example) the following object:

```
Base* b = new D1;
f(b);
```

Where is the flexibility (What it's defined as advantage that it's done in runtime) ?

Comment: Get a real book on object oriented programming.

Comment: SO isn't a programming school. Any book or tutorial on OO programming should provide motivating examples.

Comment: A common example is a graphics program, with classes for different types of objects that can be displayed. The rendering function calls `object->display()` and it invokes the method appropriate to that type.

Comment: BTW, it should be `Base *b`, since `new` returns a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't demonstrating it, but it could.

`f(b)` could be

```
void f(Base* b) {
    b->method();
}
```

Now, the actual `method()` code that's executed is determined *at* *runtime* by the type of the object that's passed in.

> How it's really allows more flexibility?

It's more flexible because the author of `f(..)` doesn't need to know how `Base:method()` works in any specific case:  You can add D3, D4, D5 classes with new implementations of `method()` without `f(..)` ever needing to know or change.

Comment: Yes, it's clear. But my qeustion was "why it's defined as advantage" (the fact that it's determined at runtime)?

Comment: You need to use a pointer to get polymorphism in C++. `b->method()`